# No context sensitivity in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr4

I am new here as I am looking for a replacement for my long friends flex & bison (using lex/yacc since over 20 years). Mainly the reason for the change is the IMHO poor C++ support.

But while looking for a replacement context sensitivity would be the main selection criteria.

Am I correctly understanding that ANTLR (be it 3 or 4, as 4 has not yet C++ support) does not have any context sensitivity (meaning automatic context sensitivity, not manual predicates) ? And I am speaking of pure syntax context, not functional context like sorting out functions and constructors in C++ language which is not the duty of parsers.

Take the following as being th easy example:

**Assume:**

- Rule to line up stmt's for the complete input is not included
- Whitespace throwing away rule not included
- Syntax may not be 100% correct but understandable for the purpose

  stmt: DEFINE SYSTEM ID '{' istmt '}' 
      | DEFINE COMPONENT ID '{' istmt '}' 
      ;

  DEFINE : 'define' ;

  SYSTEM : 'system' ;

  COMPONENT : 'component' ;

  ID : [A-Za-z][A-Za-z]* ;

  INT : [0-9]+

**Input:**

define system define { ...

Both defines will be returned as DEFINE by usual lexers as being the first longest match. The second "define" could be eaily resolved to ID by the parser passing valid tokens for the current context to the lexer, which will then select the first match among these (if any). I.e. when it comes to the ID, the lexer will identify "define" first as being the DEFINE, but this is not currently valid, so it takes the next match for the same "word" which would be ID and returns it as it is in the valid list. If no match is found in the valid list, the usual first match would be returned instead for error handling/recovery.

Of course there are more complex examples which cannot be solved at first level, but since any candidate will always macth the same lexical word looking forward buzilding and reducing a tree of possible pathes will in most cases eventually come up with a single branch identifying the correct token to be used.

Context sensitivity could be enables via an option as well as at lexer token level. I could also elaborate on a more complex example if required.

Comment: AFAIK, ANTLR3's C++ support is limited (experimental). It's been developed at a late stage of ANLR3 (development of v4 had already started, AFAIK), and it's been mostly developed by a single person. I'd be hesitant switching from Lex/Bison to ANTLR3 solely for its C++ support.

Comment: But the C support is pretty stable and fast. We are using that since a while yet. It's easy to wrap that with a C++ class.

Comment: C++ was the main reason I was looking around for an alternative, while context sensitivity would be the main reason for the actual selection.I have used flex/bison in some projects with C++ using code generated in C. I only had one project where using the "native" C++ parser was a huge advantage for th eparsing process. I currently have a project where this also would be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Bart identifies the likely controlling issue.  Some additional comments:

In Antlr, the lexer (generally) runs to completion before the parser runs, so the parser is not in a position to influence lexical context.

If the overlap in the default token value space and that specific to IDs is limited, then just include the overlap members as part of the definition of an ID (added a label as a convenience):

```
stmt: DEFINE SYSTEM id=( DEFINE | SYSTEM | COMPONENT | ID ) '{' istmt '}' 
    | DEFINE COMPONENT id=( DEFINE | SYSTEM | COMPONENT | ID ) '{' istmt '}' 
    ;
```

Where the overlap is larger or otherwise inconvenient, Antlr 4, provides lexical modes that allow explicit scoping of allowed syntax at a contextually defined points in the input stream.  Antlr 3 can achieve basically the same functionality using lexer predicates.

The design decision to decouple the lexer and parser has existed since at least Antlr 2 and likely made for separation of concerns and performance reasons. Where the lexer is driven by the parser, the lexer may have to re-lex portions of the input text many times in different contexts before the parser is able to satisfy a rule.  The Antlr lexer does everything it can, and largely succeeds, in processing the entire input text in a single pass.  Just different approaches taken with the same good intentions.

**Update: Example**

If SYSTEM and COMPONENT are adequate to define the occurrence of ID and ID is defined as a single word, the lexer becomes:

```
// mode default:
DEFINE : 'define' ;
SYSTEM : 'system' -> pushMode(id);
COMPONENT : 'component' -> pushMode(id);
LBRACE : '{' ;
RBRACE : '}' ;
WS : [ /t/r/n] -> channel(HIDDEN);

mode id:
ID : [A-Za-z][A-Za-z]* -> popMode();
IDWS : [ /t/r/n] -> channel(HIDDEN);

// or, if more than a single ID word were allowed:
mode id:
ID : [A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*
IDLBRACE : '{' -> type(LBRACE), popMode();
IDWS : [ /t/r/n] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

The parser has no awareness of lexical modes, so

```
stmt: DEFINE ( SYSTEM | COMPONENT ) ID LBRACE istmt RBRACE ;
```

Comment: If you put `DEFINE | SYSTEM | COMPONENT | ID` in a separate parser rule (like `id`), it even looks almost the same as before. You just have to make the mental shift that some work you may have been put into the lexer previously, is now done by the parser.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I know of course about these workarounds which is the actual way to deal with as long as I do not find a context sensitive parser.

Comment: As a university lecturer for parser and compiler building back in the 1990's I could of course start my own parser builder project. But unfortunately days only have 24 hours :=) Froim looking around ANTLR was for me the most promising project.

Comment: And finally when it comes to the decoupling of the lexer and the parser and the processing order I realiazed after my initial post that I forgot to mention that. Instead of the parser passing the list of allowed TOKENS to th elexer, the lexer could return a list of matching TOKENS instead of only one token. In its default (current) mode the parser would select the frst token, but could achieve context sensitivity using th eremaining ones. Making this method an option would also remove any performance penality on the lexer when not used.

Comment: As you have described it, Antlr provides lexer context sensitivity by enabling the lexer to switch to a separate, independent lexical context defined exclusively by the lexical rules implemented in/for that context.  I have added an example to my original comments.

Comment: Thanks you for the example. ANTLR modes are basically the same as start conditions (BEGIN) in lex/Flex, so this does not represent a real advantage over those, except for ist slightly cleaner approach. While this works fine for simple contextes (as my example) it can get rather hard in more complex one which in turn could be solved by a real Parser context sensitivity.

Comment: This is like a calculator application only having "+" and "-" operations  and someone (me) asking if it would be possible to get "*" as I Need to do 7*6. The answer would be, nut you could use "+" to do it (i.e. 7+7+7+7+7+7), yep sure, and what about 1093726*7382934 ? Yes it is still possible :D No, seriously, as ANTLR seems to have no implicit context sensitivity, my question would be if developpers would be willing to consider context sensitivity in the future or not. If it would be the case I would by likely switching to ANTLR and also inverst some time in getting this done.

Comment: You can post an [enhancement request](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues) for consideration by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved ambiguity of `keywords` and `Tokens`.

**src/MyGrammar.g4**

```
CONTEXT_KEYWORD_TYPE: 'type' ;
CONTEXT_KEYWORD_CONST: 'const' ;

# This token should come after all KEYWORDS
IDENTIFIER: [_a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]* ;

# This token should come after all KEYWORDS and INDENTIFIER
RENDER_ALL_KEYWORDS: 'itWillBeReplaced';

value: ...;
typeDefinition: CONTEXT_KEYWORD_TYPE '=' '{' key=(IDENTIFIER | RENDER_ALL_KEYWORDS) ':' value '}';
```

In my first build step I am transforming `src/MyGrammar.g4` into `src/gen/MyGrammar.g4`
(replace `RENDER_ALL_KEYWORDS` with list of all `CONTEXT_KEYWORD_...` separted by `|`):

**src/gen/MyGrammar.g4**

```
...
typeDefinition: CONTEXT_KEYWORD_TYPE '=' '{' key=(IDENTIFIER | CONTEXT_KEYWORD_TYPE | CONTEXT_KEYWORD_CONST
) ':' value '}';
```

Then I am compiling `src/gen/MyGrammar.g4' as my source grammar file.

In TypeScript `MyLangTreeListener` context have property `_key`:

```js
export class MyLangRootListener implements MyLangListener {
  enterTypeDefinition(ctx: TypeDefinitionContext): void {
    ctx._key;
  }
}
```

This way I have context keywords that don't conflicts with `IDENTIFIER` token. I just have to add `RENDER_ALL_KEYWORDS` and use syntax `myTokenName=(IDENTIFIER | RENDER_ALL_KEYWORDS)`.

No need to update everything when adding new context-specific keyword.